# Expected known function, got '...TimeDiffFunction not found in ....Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm trying to implement a custom function to get the time difference on two fields but I keep getting errors... I've read similar errors but the answers haven't really helped.

I've been doing this:

```
<?php
namespace Bundle\DQL;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;

/**
 * Custom DQL function returning the difference between two DateTime values
 * 
 * usage TIME_DIFF(dateTime1, dateTime2)
 */
class TimeDiffFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $dateTime1;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $dateTime2;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->dateTime1 = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();       
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->dateTime2 = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(' .
            $this->dateTime1->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ', ' .
            $this->dateTime2->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
        '))'; 
    }
}
```

config.yml

```
 orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
        dql:
           numeric_functions:
              time_diff: Bundle:DQL:TimeDiffFunction
```

controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $detail1 = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Detail')->find(96);
        //$detail2 = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Detail')->find(138);
        $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT time_diff(eng.updatedDate, eng.updatedDate) FROM Bundle\Entity\Detail eng WHERE eng.id = :id1");
        $query->setParameter('id1', $detail1->getId());
        $entities = $query->getResult();
        die(var_dump($entities));
```

doing that I get:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Bundle:DQL:TimeDiffFunction' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\EngMgmt\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php line 3070
```

but doing this on the controller instead

```
        $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT Bundle\DQL\TimeDiff(eng.updatedDate, eng.updatedDate) FROM Bundle\Entity\Detail eng WHERE eng.id = :id1");
```

i get:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected known function, got 'Bundle\DQL\TimeDiff'
```

and If i do this on the controller:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT Bundle\DQL\time_diff(eng.updatedDate, eng.updatedDate) Bundle\Entity\Detail eng WHERE eng.id = :id1");
```

i get:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 47: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '('
```

so, the question is, how can I make it work? I REALLY need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the examples from:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

Use the fully qualified class name

```
    dql:
       numeric_functions:
          time_diff: Bundle\DQL\TimeDiffFunction
```

Bundle is kind of a strange name for a Bundle.  Are your sure that is correct?

SELECT time_diff(eng.updatedDate, eng.updatedDate) ... will work once you have it installed correctly.

Comment: Bundle is correct. I omitted the company's name to avoid possible issues. I will take a look on Monday

Comment: Good luck.  I often encounter posts where they pasted code in then edited it for the question.  Problems sometimes creep in.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to solve the issue. Also, I realized there was a "Doctrine Extensions" bundle that has most of these, I installed it and created some others I needed in there.